# jQuery on() function and hover event

Tags: jquery

I'm using ajax to load XML into a table and try to do the "hover" event to change color when hovering in and out of the table row. The table row is dynamically added using AJAX. It's not working. The following is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("tr").hover(function(){
    $("#tbl1").on("hover","tr",function(){
       $(this).attr('bgcolor', "yellow");
    },
    function(){
       $(this).attr('bgcolor', "white");
    });     
});
```

and the following is the table when the page load

```
<table width="200" border="5" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" id="tbl1">
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">Index</th>
       <th scope="col">Matriks</th>
       <th scope="col">Name</th>
       <th scope="col">IC</th>
       <th scope="col">Age</th>
       <th scope="col">Photo</th>
     </tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tbl1").on("mouseenter", "tr", function() {
        $(this).attr('bgcolor', "yellow");
    }).on("mouseleave", "tr", function() {
        $(this).attr('bgcolor', "white");
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/jpMMv/2)**

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
$("#tbl1 tr").live("hover",function(){
   $(this).attr('bgcolor', "yellow");
},
function(){
   $(this).attr('bgcolor', "white");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tbl1").on("mouseenter","tr",function(){
       $(this).attr('bgcolor', "yellow");
    },
    function(){
       $(this).attr('bgcolor', "white");
    });     
});
```

hover is shorthand form of mouseenter and mouseleave events. Hover as such is not an event. And .on('hover'.. is not a valid syntax.
However you can use $("#tbl1 tr").hover(function() {}) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.css()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl1 tr").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sde8J/1/)

Comment: really need the on() function for dynamic row, otherwise not working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

hover over tr to highlight tr

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4SjZ7/1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl1 tr").hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('bgcolor', "yellow");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).attr('bgcolor', "white");
    });
});
```

if you want to hover over table and highlight tr that this code

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4SjZ7/3/

## **js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl1").hover(function () {
        $('#tbl1 tr').attr('bgcolor', "yellow");
    },
    function () {
        $('#tbl1 tr').attr('bgcolor', "white");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sde8J/2

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#tbl1 tr").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  });
});
```

Comment: It works if the row is hard coded, the problem is only when the row is added dynamically using AJAX